# What is the best solution to synchronize mysql and cloud firestore

Tags: mysql, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I am using MySQL as a main database which is not real time database. To synchronize client side data with server and keep data when offline I am considering to add real time database as a slave database in my architecture. Synchronizing data is not easy, so I want to use cloud firestore.
What I searched until now, It seems there is no pratical way to synchronize between not real time RDMS(in my case is MySQL) and cloud firestore. I can not migrate current data to cloud firestore because other services depend on that.
If there is no pratical solution for this, please suggest me the best way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but it seems there is no solution to synchronize that. To synchronize such this case, on the client side has to be implemented manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking about this as well. What I have thought up so far is this.

> Use Firestore to create a document.
> Write cloud function to listen to create events on the collection that stores that document.
> send the created document over http to a rest endpoint that stores that data on a relational db (mysql, postgres), if server is down or status code is anything other than 200, assign true to a boolean flag on the document called syncFailed.
> write a worker that periodically fetches documents where syncFailed is true and sends this document to the endpoint again until sync is a success.

THINGS TO CONSIDER
Be careful in adopting this approach with update events. You may accidently create an infinite loop that will cost you all your wealth. If you do add a update listener on a document, make sure you devise a way to avoid creating an infinite loop. You may update a document from an update-listening cloud function that in turn re-triggers this cloud function which in turn updates the document which in turn re-re-triggers this cloud function and so on. Make sure you use a boolean flag on the document or some field as a sentinel value to get out of such a looping situation.